# Horizontally align a div inside a smaller div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which I need to display under another div but have it horizontally aligned as the page size changes. Changing the page size changes the size of the first div.

I would like to place `.div2` underneath `.div1` and be center aligned.

I have created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr7Vy/) to show more clearly what I am looking for.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://jamesonstarship.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/beautiful-cat-cats-16096437-1280-800.jpg" />
    <div class="floating-container">
        <div class="floating" style="left:36%;top:26%;width:6%;height:9.5%;">
            <div class="div1">
            </div>
            <div class="div2">
                There is some content here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="floating" style="left:55%;top:38%;width:5%;height:8%;">
            <div class="div1">
            </div>
            <div class="div2">
                There is some content here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    width:100%;
}

.floating {
    position:absolute;
}

.div1 {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.div2 {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    width: 75px;
}
```

Have been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now so would really appreciate some help!

Comment: *I have a div which I need to display under another div* Which one? under what?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I would like to place div2 underneath div1 and be centre aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a pure CSS solution, you could use `%` value for the `width` of the `<div>` elements, and set a negative `margin-left` for the second div, as follows:

```css
.div1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.div2 {
    width: 300%;
    margin-left: -100%; /* <-- (300% - 100%) / 2
                                 |      |
       width of the current div --      -- width of the first div */
}
```

Also, you need to use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for the first div to calculate the width/height of the elements including the white borders:

```css
.div1 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/mr7Vy/2/)**.

### Div with a fixed width

There's **two option** to keep the second div *(I've create a new class named `.div3` for the demo)* which has a fixed `width` at the **center**.

**1)** Using CSS3 [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to calculate the proper value for the left margin.

```css
.div3 {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: calc((100% - 150px) / 2); /* <-- -1 * (150px - 100%) / 2 */
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/RDs6e/3/)**.

**2)** Using CSS3 [`translateX()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) transform function with a negative percentage value of `-50%` while the element is positioned by `left: 50%;`

```css
.div3 {
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/RDs6e/4/)**.

Comment: Nice solution, way better than mine, but is it possible to have the width of div2 fixed?

Comment: Very nice solution. Have tried it and it works great except that div2 is in some cases a fixed width - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDs6e/2/)

Comment: @hsearle I've added two solutions for the fixed width, you might want to consider using them.

Answer (score 0):

You want the text div (div2) to be centered below the white box(div1) and as far as I can understand from your code, you want div2 to be fixed 75px size and div1 variable, with percentage position and size? Well CSS is not my forte but I do not think you will be able to do that with pure CSS. 
So I can only suggest a jQuery solution like this:

```
$(".div2").each(function(){
$(this).css('margin-left',(($(this).prev().width()-$(this).width())/2));
});
```

also make sure you add this function on window like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
$(".div2").each(function(){
$(this).css('margin-left',(($(this).prev().width()-$(this).width())/2));
});
});
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wWhwX/) is a demo

If anybody know how to do this with pure CSS, or has a better solution, please fill free to share it.